# getting the contents of a cell from Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to get the value of a cell from jQgrid for use in a javascript.

I tried this

```
$('#grid').click(function(rowid,iCol,cellcontent,e,id) {
  var rowData = $(this).getRowData(id); 
  var temp= rowData['ecu'];
  var existingtext = $("#debug").html()+'<br />';
$("#debug").html(existingtext +" "+cellcontent+" "+e+" "+iCol+" "+rowid+" "+temp);
```

But I keep getting undefined and [object, object]

Answer (score 1):

Your main error is that you used [jQuery.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of jqGrid callback like [onCellSelect](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents). If you define jqGrid you can include in the list of its options any from supported callback functions like `onCellSelect`:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    // any other options which you need
    onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent) {
        $('#debug').append('<br />cellcontent=' + cellcontent +
            ', rowid=' + rowid + ', iCol=' + iCol +
            ', ecu=' + $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'ecu'));
    }
});
```